# Bulk API V2.0 Batch Result Issue

Tags: bulk-api

I have been trying to upload a csv via the the Bulk API V2. Attached is a screenshot of my issue as such.

Everything seems to go fine, except when processing the batches every single record fails. The issue is that it does not show me what the failed results are. This is only for custom objects. For standard objects such as Contacts, I have no issues with being able to retrieve the failed records.
TIA!

[image: Salesforce issue with Bulk API V2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find out why these records are failing, use the API documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/get_job_failed_results.htm#get_job_failed_results)

Once you have the `jobId` you can use invoke the REST API below

```
/services/data/vXX.X/jobs/ingest/jobID/failedResults/
```

This will return the below fields in the response,

```
sf__Error, sf__Id, Fields from the original CSV request data
```

This will tell you why these jobs failed. It could be due to validation rules or any other reason

**Update**

From the comments looks like for the version number `V` is used in the URL instead of `v`

The URL needs to be in below form

`/services/data/v51.0/jobs/ingest/<jobID>/failedResults/`

Comment: I should have mentioned this in my OP. I have tried this and it returns the following result:

[{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}]

Comment: Can you screenshot the error?

Comment: The error is exactly as above that appears in the CLI, that is what I get when I query the failed results endpoint above

Comment: Sorry I was wondering if you could share the full url you are trying to invoke?

Comment: The requested resource does not exist error happens when your url is not correct

Comment: /services/data/V51.0/jobs/ingest/{job_id}/failedResults/

Obviously the job id is replaced with the jobid

Comment: @ZachGodsell did you provide the instance URL as well? Also, note that V is small there and not capital!

Comment: I have also updated the answer. I tested it myself and if you specify `V` instead of 'v' you will get an error saying resource does not exist

Comment: Awesome that has fixed it. Something so simple.... Thanks for your help Mohith! :)